# get memory address from user

Tags: c, pointers, memory, ram

I need a little help

I use this code

```
int *p;
long b;
puts("enter address:");
scanf("%l",&b);
p=b;
printf("%d\n",*p);
```

the problem is p is a pointer and b is long,
how I can put the address that type it the user in the pointer p?

and thanks for all ;)

Answer (score 3):

`p = (int *)b;`

Please be careful of segfaults !

Comment: It should work. could you be more precise (give a sample code) ? What address do you give to your program ? Don't forget that if this address is not owned by your program, your code could raise a segmentation fault.

Comment: @mohamedesmael if you are getting a runtime error, then this program "DOES" work.